# How do you prove the Natarajan's Lemma intuitively?

Tags: machine-learning, learning-theory

Let $H$ be a hypothesis class of multiclass predictors; namely, each $h\in H$ is a function from $X$ to $[k]$.

Denote the Natarajan dimension of $H$ by $Ndim(H)$. Hope you can give me an intuitive proof of the following lemma .

$|H|\le |X|^{Ndim(H)}\cdot k^{2Ndim(H)}$

The lemma is in the book [**"Understanding Machine Learning: from theory to algorithms"**](https://www.cs.huji.ac.il/~shais/UnderstandingMachineLearning/understanding-machine-learning-theory-algorithms.pdf). You just search keywords **"Lemma 29.4"**.

Comment: Cross-posted: https://cs.stackexchange.com/q/117444/755, https://cstheory.stackexchange.com/q/45906/5038, https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3444664/14578, https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/437051/2921.   Please [do not post the same question on multiple sites](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/64068).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can check Natarajan, [On learning sets and functions](https://link.springer.com/content/pdf/10.1023/A:1022605311895.pdf) or Haussler and Long, [A generalization of Sauer's lemma](https://core.ac.uk/download/pdf/82174447.pdf).

Comment: Thank you. But those proofs are very complex, making me really sleepy. Could you give me an intuitive proof?

Comment: If you don’t like proofs, you can just accept the validity of the statement. I don’t expect there to be simpler proofs around of the lemma.